# GAMM with autocorrelation and binary data

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

Can someone recommend an approach for a `gamm` function in R that includes an autocorrelation (like the `gamm(...,correlation=corAR1())` function in `mgcv`) but that is also recommended for handling binary response data?  The `gamm()` help file has an explicit warning about using it for binary data.

"gamm performs poorly with binary data, since it uses `PQL`. It is better to use `gam` with `s(...,bs="re")` terms, or `gamm4`."

Best as I can tell, `gamm4` currently doesn't have an implementation for autocorrelation.

Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: if you don't get an answer here you might try on `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org`.  I suspect you're largely out of luck/will have to rely on build-your-own solutions like AD Model Builder, Template Model Builder, etc. ... or run some simulations to see just how bad PQL actually is on your data.  If you're not primarily interested in the estimates of the random-effects variances, the fixed-effect estimates might not be too bad ...

Comment: Thank you, @BenBolker. And by the way, Ecological Models and Data in R is one of my favorite references!